# > jQuery Child Selector without a parent allowed?

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector, parent

Quick question, is a [jQuery child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) without a parent ever valid? If so, how would you use it?

Example of the jQuery child selector:

```
$('ul > li')
```

Example of jQuery child selector without parent:

```
$('> li')
```

The second example above doesn't work. However I can't remember if I saw it in the past before or I've seen something advance like:

```
$('ul').not('>li')
```

Doesn't really work either (but doesn't pop up an error message, so it's just ignored?)

So my question is would you **EVER** use a child selector without a parent, and have it be a valid jQuery selector.

Thanks, sorry if question is dumb. :)

---

Edit:

Along with Nick's jQuery.find example on the bottom, another use case is

```
$('ul:has(>li)')
```

Note: that $('ul').has('>li') is wrong and should be written

```
$('ul').has('ul>li')
```

---

AND for not()

Not sure if I have it correct, but you wouldn't ever use a > inside of not() directy because not() only concern about one element, while > compares multiple elements. However you can do something like

```
$('li:not(:has(>p))'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it works without a parent, **but** it can't be on the *default* context, because your `<li>` isn't a *`direct`* child of a `document`.  Also, it wouldn't make any sense by itself really, since it's a direct child of *something*, it'd be the same as `$("li")`.

When would it be used? possibly to cut down on code, for example:

```
$(this).find("> li > span a");
//as opposed to not being able to start with it:
$(this).children("li").children("span").find("a");
```

Comment: Whoa yeh, $(this).find("> li > span a"); is what I'm talking about... would it work for .has() & .not() as well??

Comment: @Quang - In some cases yes, others, no, the `>` and `:has()` don't get along so nicely, it's a bug in sizzle with the way the selector parts are popped, I need to put in a bug report on that one.

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying to wrap my head around what a '>' with no parent does. In your example what the difference between $(this).find("> li > span a") AND $(this).find("li > span a")  ?  First one direct child, second one all descendants?

Comment: @Quang - The first will only find a `<li>` that's an *immediate* child of `this`, the second will start with a `<li>` anywhere beneath.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I got it. Keep forgetting how > works, always confuse it with :first / :first-child

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a situation that requires a child selector without a parent. The child selector is used to select immediate children of a parent element. If there is no parent element, whose children should be selected?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want that ?

You could always use `$('* > li')` although i can't really see what that would accomplish, as `li` should always be a child of something `ul` or `ol`