# What will the following piece of code doing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

What is this find in jquery actually doing?

```
find('> a > img').attr('src');
```

I am not sure of the > selector . [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp)  it tells that the usage is (parent > child) selects all elements that are a direct child of the specified element. But here in find the parent is not at all specified. So what is happening here?

Comment: Presumably there is something before `find`!

Comment: This will find all direct *child elements* of the *selector* you're calling `.find()` on, like: `var images = $('body').find('> a > img');`.

Comment: Probably that the a tag is the direct child of anything else.

See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3992525/2955744

Comment: Helps if you check the documentation for selectors: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as `.children('a').children('img').attr('src')`

Answer (score 1):

It will img source inside anchor tag,but parent element should be specified to find for ex:

```
$('.parent-class').find('>a > img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You would pass an object to `find()`, which would act as the parent selector. Given this markup:

```
<div class="my_div">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/my_img.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

`$('.my_div').find('> a > img')` should return the image as the object, while `$('.my_div').find('> a > img').attr('src')` should return "my_img.jpg"

I'll also point out that '>' is a CSS selector; it's not unique to jQuery. In vanilla CSS `.my_div > a > img` would select any `<img>` that was a direct descendant of any `<a>` that **is in turn** a direct descendant of `.my_div`. In most instances this degree of *specificity* would be actually be overkill.

Comment: what if there are n <a href> inside my_div ?

Comment: Do you mean n `<img>`? Current it is looking for `<img>` that are * direct descendants* of `<a>`, which in turn have to be *direct descendants* of `.my_div`. Having multiple `<a>` per se wouldn't change that, unless they also contained `<img>`

Comment: Given the above selectors:

 - `.my_div -> <a> -> <img>` Match
 - `.my_div -> <a>` No match
 - `.my_div -> <img> ` No match
 - `.my_div -> <a> -> <span> -> <img>` No match

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is supposed to work:

```
var a = $("#outerDiv").find('> a > img').attr('src');
$("#mydiv").html(a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XLRGm/